# Is it possible to fetch all the results into an array using fetchAll method

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

**Is it possible to fill an array from the statement->fetchAll()
(PDO fetchAll)?**

```
  public function showDetails()
        {
        $db = ConnectDatabase::getInstance();
        $connect = $db->getConnection();
        $statment = $connect->query('SELECT * FROM users');
        $result = $statment->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: Depends on how many results there are, and how much memory you have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
$array = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In order to echo an ARRAY, you must use print like so:

```
print_r($member2->showDetails());
```

That being said, it won't be very... pretty. Use a loop to format how you want:

```
$users = $member2->showDetails();

foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user['User_Name'];
}
```

Where 'col1' is a column you want to echo.

Comment: Yeah excatly what I've already tried it gives this error: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project1\testingProject1.php on line 47
Array

Comment: You can't simply echo an array. Try print_r($array) instead. Or loop through it if you want to echo specific values in the array.

Comment: @SarahChaygani note it's FETCH_ASSOC, not FETCH_ASSO. Might make a difference.

Comment: Added above,Please check it out.

Comment: the line 47 is where I'm testing the method.echo $member2->showDetails();

Comment: There, my answer should now highlight what is wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123066/discussion-between-sarah-chaygani-and-pachonk).